# Trying to select an i2c address throws ioctl failed: invalid argument

Tags: raspberry-pi, common-lisp, i2c, sbcl, ioctl

I am building a program in Common Lisp, which communicates via i2c to a pca9685 using sysfs on a raspberry pi 3B+.

When initializing the device, I need to select the pca by using `(ioctl fd +i2c-slave+ addr)` where `+i2c-slave+ = xf0703` (command for selecting slave) and `addr = 0x40` (for pca9685)

However from the call I get an error:

```lisp
IOCTL 1795 failed: Invalid argument
[Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]
0: ((SETF I2C::IOCTL) 64 10 1795)
1: (I2C:I2C-START #S(I2C:I2C-DEV :FILENAME "/dev/i2c-1" :DEV 1 :ADDR 64))
```

I am using the ioctl implementation from [cl-spidev](https://github.com/Shinmera/cl-spidev/blob/master/ioctl.lisp).

Since I am on sbcl, the relevant function is

```lisp
(defun (setf ioctl) (arg fd cmd)
  (sb-alien:with-alien ((value sb-alien:int))
    (setf value arg)
    (multiple-value-bind (wonp error)
        (sb-unix:unix-ioctl (stream-fd fd)
                            (if (< cmd (expt 2 31)) cmd (- cmd (expt 2 32)))
                            (sb-alien:alien-sap (sb-alien:addr value)))
      (unless wonp
        (error "IOCTL ~a failed: ~a" cmd (sb-impl::strerror error))))
    arg))
```

and it is called like this

```lisp
(setf (ioctl fd cl-i2c-lli:+i2c-slave+) addr)
```

My current guess is that the ioctl function is passing a pointer, while it should be a plain long (according to [the docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/i2c/dev-interface.html)), but still am unable to wrap my head around it completely. Am I missing something obvious?

The Adafruit python library, and [some](https://github.com/Digilent/linux-userspace-examples/blob/a835c8b4caf8d7567a9eb011654dbcb5b856f885/i2c_example_linux/src/i2c.c#L42) example C implementations work in the same way.

**Notes**

- Also tried with `I2C_SLAVE_FORCE`, and got the same result.
- How to pass the integer to the foreign call as a value? Is it possible?
- `i2cdetect` confirms that there is a device on `#x40`, successfully read some registers with `i2cget`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your supposition is correct, this wrapper function that you are using calls `ioctl` with a pointer to your value instead of the value.

Have you tried simply `(sb-unix:unix-ioctl fd cl-i2c-lli:+i2c-slave+ addr)`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this. I *think* `unix-ioctl` can only take a pointer, iirc, but will check again.

Comment: `sb-sys:int-sap` will convert a number to a pointer

Comment: So I do not get the error this way, though it is still not working. Got to debug my circuits now. According to my logging everything should be fine :) Thanks again.
p.s.: weird that `unix-ioctl` returns a boolean, I somehow expected an int.